# Pyodbc bulk insert into Teradata table

Tags: python-3.x, teradata, pyodbc, bulkinsert, teradatasql

How do I insert 10-50k+ rows (from e.g. Series or Dataframe) into a Teradata table effectively with Pyodbc?

**Background**:

- I am building a GUI app in Python
- No Teradata libraries can be used (as I fail to package the software with those libs)

Comment: *"No Teradata libraries can be used"* - Does that include "no Teradata ODBC driver"?

Comment: Yes, Teradata ODBC driver can be used.

Comment: Okay, and does your app already have a dependency on pandas?

Comment: Yes it has panda dependencies

Comment: Okay, then it's not that big of a leap to add in [SQLAlchemy](https://pypi.org/project/SQLAlchemy/) and [teradatasqlalchemy](https://pypi.org/project/teradatasqlalchemy/) and then you can presumably use pandas' `to_sql` method to upload the data.

Comment: I have tried exactly that, it runs successfully before packaging. But fails after packaging. Basically to_sql depends on SQLalchemy which in turn depdends on teradatasqlalchemy.. which causes the fail after packaging.

Comment: So you'd rather create an app that requires separate install of a native ODBC driver? Parameterized INSERT with `executemany` is a bit faster than individual INSERT statements, though still not "fast".

Comment: Fred, haven't tried using different odbc driver. I use mssql for other db connection in app. If that driver would help resolve the issue that would be great!